# In Rails, is there a way to call request.request_uri in a class (not a controller)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-analytics

I'm building a pageview counter for my app using the Garb Ruby wrapper for the Google Analytics API. Doing so means creating a new Module in the 'lib' folder, in which I create a class like this:

```
#lib/Analyze.rb

...
class Report
  extend Garb::Resource
  metrics :pageviews
  dimensions :page_path
  filters :page_path.eql => '/' #the path of the page I instantiate this class on
end

#followed by a method for instantiating this class
```

I need filters :page_path.eql => to be the path of the page in which I call the method. I've tried things like request.request_uri or url_for(:action => 'show' :controllers => 'users' :id => params[:id]) but don't know how to specify the page path in this class definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will break MVC encapsulation - I *think* you should be creating a before filter in your application_controller that passes the request data you need to your class.

**EDIT**

If you want to build a one-off report for a particular page, I think you'll need to do something like this:

```
profile = Garb::Profile.first('UA-XXXX-XX')

report = Garb::Report.new(profile)
report.metrics :pageviews
report.dimensions :page_path
report.filters :page_path.eql => request.request_uri 

report.results
```

Again, if you're having this on every page, a before filter would be wise, I think. Pretty sure it's going to slow your app down a lot, though.

[This is covered in the docs.](http://github.com/vigetlabs/garb)

Comment: What does passing request data back to the class look like? I know I can't just pass a variable into the class definition. Sorry, still a fairly new programmer.

Comment: I think you want to build a one-off report for each page - I've updated my answer

Comment: Okay, this does work for me but also makes it slower. If you come up with any other ways of doing it, love to know. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah - it will slow it down as you're making a request to Analytics on each page load. You could cache the values returned, and decouple the request for the report by doing it in a background job. This won't give you up-to-the-second counters, but it will alleviate the slowness.